# Python Non-Blocking Reading of Commands

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth

I'm trying to read command outputs from hcitools in Linux (it scans for bluetooth devices).

I just need to read the first line that it returns, as sometimes this tool has an error. The issue is that this tool continues to run in a infinite loop, which locks up the rest of my Python script. The script is run with sudo so that it has root privileges to use the hcitool command.

I have created a class to try to pipe the data in asynchronously:

```
class ASyncThread(threading.Thread): #pOpen read and readline are blocking. So we must use an async thread to read from hciTool
  def __init__(self, command, parameters = []):
    self.stdout = None
    self.stderr = None
    self.command = command
    self.parameters = parameters
    self.process = None
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

  def run(self):
    if len(self.command) >= 1:
      self.process = subprocess.Popen([self.command] + self.parameters, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      self.stdout, self.stderr = self.process.communicate()
    else:
      print "[ASyncThread::run()] Error: Empty command given."

  def terminate(self):
    try:
      self.process.terminate()
    except Exception, ex:
      print "[ASyncThread::terminate()] Error: ", ex
```

And I'm calling it with:

```
  print "Checking HCI Tool Status..."

  hciThread = ASyncThread("/usr/local/bin/hciconfig", ["lescan"])
  hciThread.start()
  time.sleep(1) #Give the program time to run.
  hciThread.terminate() #If terminate is not placed here, it locks up my Python script when the thread is joined.
  hciThread.join()

  outputText = hciThread.stdout + " | " + hciThread.stderr
```

When this is run, the output is just " | ".
If I run this command:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/hcitool lescan
```

It instantly starts working immediately:

```
slyke@ubuntu ~ $ sudo hcitool lescan
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
```

I've been working on this for a few hours now. I originally tried to do this with pOpen, but read() and readline() are both blocking. This is not normally a problem, except that there may not be an error, or any data produced by this command, so my Python script hangs. This is why I moved to threading, so it can wait for a second before stopping it, and continuing on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you cannot possibly join a thread, after you have just terminated it on the line above.

Your particular issue about doing an lescan is probably better solved with the solution from mikerr/btle-scan.py - https://gist.github.com/mikerr/372911c955e2a94b96089fbc300c2b5d